# Verify method was called on returned mock

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm using [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/) to unit test my factory, and subsequent execution of it's product.

I have a `ParameterAlgorithmFactory` (returns the algorithms to calculate a report parameter as a `IVisibilityParameterAlgorithm`) and a method within the factory which calls `Execute()` on each of these.

In order to test this I have written a unit test like so:

```
//Verfiy that execute is called on all algorithms produced by factory
[TestMethod]
public void ParameterAlgorithmFactory_ReturnedAlgorithm_ExpectExceuteCalled()
{
    var mockFactory = new Mock<IParameterAlgorithmFactory>();
    var parameterAlgorithm = new Mock<IVisibilityParameterAlgorithm>();

    mockFactory.Setup(x => x.Create(LineType.Adjustment)).Returns(parameterAlgorithm.Object);

    new ReportParameters().CreateParameters(new DataSet(), mockFactory.Object);

    parameterAlgorithm.Verify(x=> x.Execute(new DataSet()));
 }
```

As you can see I'm returning a mock algorithm (`parameterAlgorithm`) from my mock factory, which I then want to verfiy has had `Execute()` called.

However I am consistantly getting:

> Moq.MockException:  Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but
>   was never performed: x => x.Execute(new DataSet())

*even though* I can debug and *see* the line being `Execute()`ed.

Perhaps I'm doing too much in my factory (returning an algorithm and executing it) or perhaps I'm using Moq in the **wrong way**?

Any feedback much appreciated on the cause of this test failure is appreciated.

Comment: You should probably use `It.IsAny<DataSet>()` instead of `new DataSet()` - verification might be using reference equality for parameters instead of 'type'/stub equality.

Comment: Can you provide the details of `ReportParameters.CreateParameters`? Are you sure that you call `Create` with `LineType.Adjustment` as parameter?

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek - It looks like `It.IsAny<DataSet>()` has done the trick!  I'll read up on this aspect so I understand and use in the future.  If you want to write this up as a answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you should use `It.IsAny<DataSet>()` instead of `new DataSet()` as a parameter for verification.

It seems that Moq compares references and not 'types', so you'll end up with failed verification. `It.IsAny<DataSet>()` is exactly what should be used here instead if you just want a stub parameter.